# Roster.getEntries returning 0 with asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I created a sendchat text messages, but I cant get the status of other users by using roster method.

```
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

                Log.e("entry count",""+roster.getEntryCount());

                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                Log.e("Roster Entries",""+roster.getEntries().size());
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                    if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");                
                }



            } catch (XMPPException ex) {

                setConnection(null);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't added users to roster list. After adding users to roster list only, we can get the user details.

Comment: adding roster is not enough, you need to add subscription too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add :

```
If(!Roster.IsLoaded()) 
   Roster.reloadAndWait();
```

Before the line :

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
```

Comment: this is still giving me 0 entries

Comment: you need to add subscription too in openfire